# How can i install ET Legacy from GitHub on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, 64-bit

My problem is that I want to install ET Legacy from GitHub, but I can't figure out what package is needed to be downloaded from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc. The only thing I could figure out (with some help of an another site's user), is that I need one of the lstdc++ packages. 
The full terminal output can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9919220/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output shows you have `g++` installed, which means you have `libstdc++-4.8-dev` installed as well. Besides, it looks like the error is about 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit system, so you probably need to install [`g++-multilib`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/g++-multilib).

```
sudo apt install g++-multilib
```